# ¿Es correcto que un usuario le ayude a otro a subir de reputación?

Tags: discusión, reputación, convenciones-sociales

Un usuario ha duplicado en los últimos 30 minutos unas diez respuestas de preguntas no tan nuevas y todas han sido aceptadas por encima de las que ya habían respondido a la pregunta. Varias habían sido preguntadas por un mismo usuario.

Ya las reporté, sin embargo me queda la duda: ¿es correcto que un usuario le ayude a otro a subir de reputación?

Comment: Muchas gracias por reportarlo . No, no es aceptable "ayudar" a subir la reputación. Inicio la investigación al respecto. Un saludo

Comment: Ambos usuarios indican que son de la misma localidad, parece un caso bastante claro de _compinchamiento_. Dicho lo cual, no creo bueno publicar nombres aquí: si lo reportaste para que los moderadores lo investiguen, ¿cuál es el objetivo de hacerlo público? Como mucho podrías hablar de ello pero sin mencionar nombres, por aquello de la presunción de inocencia.

Comment: No, en ningun caso es aceptable subir reputacion con una cuenta falsa, o compinchandose con otra persona.

Comment: Gracias a todos por su guía.

Comment: @fedorqui para el caso, deberiamos eliminar la version original de este post ;)

Comment: @gbianchi cierto, aunque eso solo lo pueden hacer los moderadores, eliminando la primera versión de la publicación. Era deseable evitar el efecto Meta, pero veo que no fue así y se votó en contra de forma masiva.

Comment: @fedorqui disculpa a que te refieres con el *efecto meta*?

Comment: @anonimo el *efecto meta* es el efecto causado por publicar algo respecto a una pregunta o usuario en Meta, por ejemplo en este caso el OP publico el nombre del usuario que parece haber hecho trampa por lo que muchos lectores de este post comenzaron a dar downvotes a las respuestas solo por el hecho de la trampa y no en si por valorar la respuesta.

Comment: @anonimo ese efecto es un ruido muy fuerte que puede ser negativo para el usuario como en este caso pero tambien puede ser positivo, por ejemplo un usuario publica: *¿por qué dieron un downvote a mi pregunta?* y mucha gente por lástima o querer restaurar los puntos le da un upvote. Nuevamente se dio el voto sin tomar en cuenta la publicación en sí sino por otros motivos

Comment: @anonimo anteriormente no lo habia visto aca pero hoy desgraciadamente lo ví, en SOen ya se conoce ese efecto indeseado y por ello se evita que publiquen información sensible como nombres de usuarios que pudieron haber cometido algo indebido salvo que sea necesario.

Comment: Entendido y comprendido Gracias  @eyllanesc

Comment: @anonimo genial, por ello siempre debemos tomar conciencia de lo que publiquemos ya que pueden traer consecuencias positivas o negativas para todos.

Comment: @anonimo una respuesta y concisa esta en: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/235225/what-is-the-meta-effect , adios.

Comment: @anonimo exactamente lo que comentó eyllanesc. Para tener la info en castellano, creé la pregunta en Meta: [¿Qué es el efecto Meta?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4052/83).

Comment: Aún me queda la duda sobre cómo se resuelve la situación planteada. ¿Hay algo sobre esto en alguna parte? ¿Se le llama la atención al OP que se dedicó a revertir de forma sistemática la aceptación de respuestas auténticas por respuestas claramente  plagiadas? Sé que será un caso aislado, es la primera vez que veo algo parecido, pero creo que afecta a la calidad del sitio.

Comment: @A.Cedano me pasaba lo mismo. Llevo 7 años en SE y es la primera vez que veo esto, por eso pregunté.

Comment: @A.Cedano esos casos son dificiles de detectar, en SOes es la primera vez que lo veo, pero en SOen he detectado un par de ellos porque me dedico a ciertas etiquetas específicas por lo que tengo más atención a esas *jugadas*, el trámite normal es que reciban una sanción pero eso es tarea de los moderadores diamantados ya que ellos tienen más información para validar y tambien más poderes para castigar.

Comment: Gracias por el dato @eyllanesc.