# ¿Qué es el efecto Meta?

Tags: soporte, meta, glosario

Con frecuencia oigo hablar sobre el concepto *efecto Meta*, pero no acabo de saber a qué se refieren con ello. ¿Alguien podría aclararme en qué consiste?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

El efecto Meta es el efecto de mencionar en Meta una publicación (o usuario) del sitio (o de otro sitio).

Por el hecho de mencionarla, la publicación (o el usuario) recibe mucha más atención de la que habría recibido normalmente, de modo que en muchos casos acaba recibiendo muchos votos. Esos votos pueden ser positivos o negativos dependiendo del caso, pero en cualquier caso serán votos provocados por el efecto arrastre de mencionarlo en Meta, en lugar de por el desarrollo orgánico del sitio.

En cualquier caso siempre es bueno recordar la máxima de: [Votemos por contenido, no por personas](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1935/83).

Comment: Adaptado de [What is the “meta effect”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/235225/209901) y [The Many Memes of Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/204311/209901)

Comment: Entonces es malo o bueno? Para el usuario o la comunidad

Comment: @JuanRivera ni malo ni bueno, simplemente... es. Yo creo que debería tender a evitarse si es en relación a los votos, pues todo puntaje en las publicaciones debería ceñirse a la publicación en sí, no a otras cosas "meta".