# ¿Por qué a veces no sale la opción de reportar por muy baja calidad?

Tags: soporte

No es la primera vez que voy a reportar una pregunta de baja calidad y no me aparece la opción de "muy baja calidad" por lo que le doy a "se necesita intervención de un moderador" y ahí escribo muy baja calidad, pero me gustaría saber por que pasa esto.

> Dejo esta pregunta como ejemplo que es la última en la que me ha pasado :
>
> - [Calculadora en python con interfaz gráfica(Tkinter) SIN utilizar eval](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/253953/calculadora-en-python-con-interfaz-gr%C3%A1ficatkinter-sin-utilizar-eval)
>
> [image: Imagen de muestra]

## En cambio, **en esta otra pregunta**: [Porque con el mismo código en dos app uno muestra el PDF y el otro no](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/253290/porque-con-el-mismo-c%C3%B3digo-en-dos-app-uno-muestra-el-pdf-y-el-otro-no)

> Si me sale la opción de reportar por muy baja calidad. [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
>
> ## Al igual que aquí ([¿Qué es yield en python?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/254297/qu%C3%A9-es-yield-en-python)), **pregunta que no he reportado** tampoco me sale el de mala calidad.
>
> [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tu dices: *por lo que le doy a "se necesita intervención de un moderador" y ahí escribo muy baja calidad*, si estas señalando que tecnicamente es de baja calidad no deberias reportarlo ante un moderador ya que las cuestiones técnicas lo deben resolver la comunidad ya que generalmente hay expertos en cada hilo. Si es otro caso tendrias que evaluar si necesitas que un moderador diamantado lo necesita tramitar, recuerdo que su tiempo es muy valioso :-). Mi regla para estos casos es: Si no lo puede resolver la comunidad entonces recien lo reporto a un moderador.

Comment: Revisando la pregunta que señalas la opción correcta es *deberia ser cerrada...* ->  *no está claro lo que se pregunta*. Yo pienso que si lo has reportado a un moderador este deberia rechazarlo.

Comment: @eyllanesc me lo apunto para la próxima, de todas formas, mi pregunta es **¿por que no me aparece para reportar por muy baja calidad?** .

Comment: @Aritzbn me parece raro pero observo en la parte inferior de tu primera imagen en color rojo: *Este es el reporte que has enviado* por lo que presumo que ya enviaste un reporte y por lo tanto ya no puedes reenviarlo. Te recomiendo revisar tus reportes.

Comment: @eyllanesc el reporte lo envié al no encontrar el de "muy baja calidad", no es la primera vez que me pasa y por eso es que he venido a meta en busca de aclarar mis dudas, tal vez no sea yo quien deba de fijarse en los reportes. [Edito de nuevo con otro ejemplo que me he encontrado y que no he reportado previamente]

Comment: @Aritzbn sospecho que la opción "muy baja calidad" en preguntas que tengan al menos un +1 como puntuación. En el post que señalas hay una puntuación de 1 por lo que el sistema asume que es de buena calidad. Por otro lado te pido que cuando coloques imagenes de preguntas o post no publiques un enlace  a ese post y borres el nombre del post(al menos difuminalo) ya que estas generando un [efecto meta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4052/qu%c3%a9-es-el-efecto-meta)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Empiricamente he descubierto que si una publicación tiene puntuación >= 1 el sistema elimina la opción *muy baja calidad* ya que supongo que el sistema concluye que no lo es porque al menos la mayoria de votantes de esa pregunta considera que es de buena calidad.

---

<sub>Te recomiendo no publicar los enlaces a las preguntas, editar las imagenes para que sea imposible saber la ubicación de la publicación y el autor de la pregunta ya que actualmente estas generando el [efecto meta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4052/qu%c3%a9-es-el-efecto-meta)</sub>

Comment: 1: habitualmente reviso meticulosamente que reporto y cómo lo reporto, un despiste lo puede tener cualquiera. 2. Me parece completamente fuera de lugar que comentes lo de "mi error" en una respuesta, todo lo que está en la segunda parte sobra, ya me lo has dicho en los comentarios. 3. He puesto 3 ejemplos que creía **absolutamente necesarios** para poder exponer mis dudas, con el fin de resolver mis dudas, ya que en los comentarios os estabáis yendo por la ramas. 4: Gracias por resolverme la duda, me ha pasado más de una vez revisando las colas y en el chat no me dijeron a que se debía.

Comment: @Aritzbn No lo tomes a mal, mi idea es que otros miembros de la comunidad no comentan esos errores sin intención. Asi que en general no publiques información sensible si no es necesario. Bastaba con ver la votación para conocer la causa.

Comment: no lo tomo a mal , siento si mi tono pareció agresivo, la falta de lenguaje corporal pasa factura. En este caso me pareció que poner enlaces era lo apropiado, trataré de evitarlo para próximas consultas.