# ¿Está bien reportar una respuesta que no es y además es de mal gusto?

Tags: discusión, moderación

Acabo de ver una respuesta... que no es respuesta (y la reporté como tal) pero además, es un comentario que trata de ser un chiste (no lo es) y es además clasista.

Cuando los usuarios hacen ese tipo de comentarios, ¿los moderadores hacen algo?

Comment: la reportaste hace 8 min.. danos aire!!!! :p

Comment: La reporté por no ser respuesta. Lo que digo es que, además de no ser respuesta de nada, es irrespeto del usuario al OP. No los estoy acosando, @gbianchi, ni más faltaba. Es para que, además de hacer lo que hacen cuando no es respuesta, regañen al usuario o algo. Lo que está diciendo ahí es algo como "eso le pasa por estudiar en escuela pública"

Comment: El del negativo/no negativo soy yo, no @gbianchi (no vayas a pensar que es él)

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro no trates de encubrir a gbianchi, que yo sé que fue él :P

Comment: A puntito estuve de sacar el martillo de banear... luego me dije "nah, el comentario de '¿los moderadores hacen algo?' no es por ti, es por @gbianchi que nunca hace nada" y volví a guardar el martillo.

Comment: Si ya reportaste a un moderador, la solución está en camino. No es buena práctica apuntar a la publicación para evitar el [Efecto Meta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4052/83) contra el usuario. Como además ya se ha borrado y pocos usuarios pueden verlo, el enlace ya apenas tiene utilidad. Lo elimino pues.

Comment: El título de la pregunta es si está bien reportar contenido inadecuado (respuesta obvia: **claro que sí**). Pero el cuerpo de la pregunta es una crítica velada a la moderación actual. Creo que voy a reportar tu pregunta de meta por inadecuada, ya que el título y el contenido no concuerdan.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster es en serio? decir que es una crítica velada es ponerle tono y suponer cosas. Lo que dice la pregunta es claro: ¿                                                                                                            los moderadores hacen algo cuando el usuario hace un chiste clasista?

Comment: @Alfabravo ¿Estás seguro de que la pregunta es "*¿Los moderadores hacen algo cuando el usuario hace un chiste clasista?*"? ¿la pregunta no es "*¿Está bien reportar una respuesta que no es y además es de mal gusto?*"?

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster estoy segurísimo. Si los moderadores que estaban esa noche, que eran dos, me dicen "no podemos hacer nada aparte de cerrar", eso también respondía mi pregunta. Que tú la quieras leer con tono o que quieras leer entre líneas no es mi responsabilidad

Comment: @Alfabravo si estás segurísimo de que la pregunta es "A" y no "B", deberías editar el título de la pregunta para que refleje "B" y no "A".

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster no. Si me dicen que no pueden hacer nada por B, yo no hago A.

Comment: Si. Si la pregunta es "¿Puedo reportar X?" entonces el contenido de tu publicación está mal. Si la pregunta es "¿Por qué los moderadores no hacen Y?" entonces el título de tu publicación está mal. La publicación va de lo que puedes hacer o de lo que hacen los moderadores… decídete.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster La primera premisa es falsa, la segunda contiene una pregunta que no hice. Con premisas falsas no hay conversación posible.

Comment: Tienes razón @Alfabravo no hay debate posible con alguien que hace una pregunta del tipo "¿Está bien hacer X?" y después dice no haberlo hecho cuando es perfectamente visible en el título de la pregunta. Lo mismo cuando hace una pregunta del tipo "¿Los moderadores hacen Y cuando sucede una cosa que no me gusta?" y niega que forme parte de un juicio hacia la tarea de moderación. Gracias por tu tiempo.

Answer (score 8):

La respuesta ha sido borrada en cuanto se reportó y puso en conocimiento de los moderadores (gracias @gbianchi)

---

Lo que ocurre con este tipo de publicaciones suele ser uno de estos:

- Son reportadas automáticamente por el sistema (debido a su extensión y contenido) y a los moderadores nos llega una notificación para que la revisemos.
- Los usuarios las reportan (como hiciste) y a los moderadores nos llega una notificación para que revisemos la publicación.
- Los propios moderadores usando el sitio encuentran la publicación problemática y la borran.

Hay un cuarto caso que no suele ser muy común, pero ocurre a veces: nadie se da cuenta y la publicación queda ahí por años hasta que algún usuario la encuentra y la reporta.

---

Sobre las consecuencias. Normalmente se limita al borrado de la respuesta problemática y ahí queda la cosa.

Si es algo más grave, nos ponemos en contacto con el usuario y puede conllevar suspensión. (En el caso que reportaste, no lo considero grave ya que parece algo en plan jocoso pero no *ofensivo*, la típica rivalidad entre universidades/ciudades)

Ahora, el borrado, al ser por un moderador tras un reporte, lleva un -1 asociado. Y eso trae consecuencias: si el usuario no tiene mucha experiencia en el sitio (lo normal en estos casos), ese -1 va a hacer que acabe bloqueado y no pueda escribir más respuestas hasta que no mejore su reputación. Así que las gracias suelen salir caras.

Otra cosa que puede ocurrir: si las únicas aportaciones del usuario son gracias de ese tipo o comentarios que pueden considerarse abusivos/problemáticos, se puede destruir el usuario.

Comment: Gracias por gestionarlo tan rápido. Lo que no entiendo es cuando mencionas que "el borrado, al ser por un moderador tras un reporte, lleva un -1 asociado". ¿A qué -1 te refieres exactamente? ¿Reputación?

Comment: @fedorqui la respuesta recibe un -1 automáticamente antes de ser borrada. Ocurre cuando le damos a eliminar o editar una publicación que ha sido reportada. Ese -1 no es un voto del moderador, que puede votar en la publicación (y darle un +1/-1 adicional). Aunque no se si ese comportamiento depende del tipo de reporte.

Comment: Ah vale. Efectivamente, las publicaciones en la cola de baja calidad reciben un voto negativo automático si el reporte (si no es automático) se da por válido, ya sea borrando o editando esa publicación. Hay cierta discusión en Meta.SE sobre el tema, que hace que cada vez menos casuísticas tengan ese auto-voto negativo: [Let's Remove The Auto Downvote On Validated VLQ Flags (On Questions)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/310974/209901) y _Posts are [no longer automatically downvoted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/330415/377214) as a result of helpful "low quality" autoflags_

Comment: Habría que aclarar que, en general, no se hace un borrado sino una ocultación. Después de que el moderador borre todavía hay personas que pueden verlo.